# Can a notable claim be implied?

Tags: discussion

In the UK there are [laws](https://www.cambridgeshire.gov.uk/residents/children-and-families/schools-&-learning/education-your-rights-and-responsibilities/non-attendance-and-the-law/) that required attendance at school in which non-attendance can result in parents can get fined for missing a day of school.

My assumption is that these laws are in place to improve truancy and hence improve educational outcomes. So far I have not been able to find any direct claims about the introduction of the laws and the improvements in education but believe it would be the ultimate claim behind the laws.

If either of the below questions was asked would the existence of truancy laws in the UK be sufficient to have a notable claim

1. Do the UK truancy laws reduce the truancy rates
2. Do the UK truancy laws improve the educational outcomes for students.

Can these questions be asked on the basis of the laws alone

Comment: I don't think so, maybe schools are like daycare,  reduce crime,  integrate society or crush the resistance to mundane workplaces.

Comment: Either a claim is notable (i.e. people actually claim that) or is it implicit (i.e. people think that but don't say so). The two concepts are at odds.